# Detect anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Is there a way to detect function defined using 'new Function' and using 'function'.

toString almost solves the problem but it is still possible to have ambiguity:

new Function:

```
new Function("").toString()
// =>
function anonymous() {

}
```

using function:

```
(function anonymous() {

}).toString()
// =>
function anonymous() {

}
```

When name is 'anonymous' it could be first or second option.

Comment: What do you mean, "detect"?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @KennethK. Detect I mean to know how it was created.

Comment: @epascarello I need it to know that function will be called in a global context and I cannot use any captured variables.
For instance

function work() {
 var x = "string";
 var f = new Function("alert(x)");
}

setTimeout(f, 0); // The function will fail cause 'x' is unknown in global scope.

Comment: It sounds from this comment that you need to re-ask your question. You seem to want to know about scope, not about the source code...

Comment: Well, I want to know whether there are any variables used in function that depends on scope. But it will be enough to know whether function is created dynamically.